# Android "Cannot play this video" in VideoView for tablet API-23

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am facing this weird behavior for VideoView. I have video saved in my **raw** directory (**myvideo.mp4**). I am not sure, what's going on, video is playing fine in most of the devices but for few of them like Nexus 7 800 x 1280  API 23  it's not working. I am really blocked at this point. I would appreciate any help at all.

Video details are :

```
Type: Video
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Resolution: 1080x1920
Display resolution: 1080x1920
Frame rate: 25
```

For Nexus 5 and other devices, it's working fine.

For tablets, I have tested on

1. WSVGA_API_23 **600×1024: mdpi 23 Android 6.0** (Google APIs) x86 4 GB - Works fine.

2. Pixel_C_API_23 **2560 × 1800: xhdpi 23 Android 6.0** (Google APIs)  x86 4 GB - Works fine.

3. Nexus_7_API_23_2 **1200 × 1920: xhdpi   23  Android 6.0** (Google APIs) x86 4 GB - Works fine.


4. Nexus_7_API_23 **800 × 1280: tvdpi 23 Android 6.0** (Google APIs)   x86_64  4 GB - **Shows message "Cannot play this video"**.


Here is my code.

```
final String uri = "android.resource://com.example/"+R.raw.myvideo;
final Uri video = Uri.parse(uri);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
mVideoView.start();
```

This is the log:

```
08-28 22:03:17.017 ? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xf3f48000 in tid 8694 (NPDecoder-CL)
08-28 22:03:17.118 ? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-28 22:03:17.118 ? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:6.0/MASTER/4174734:userdebug/test-keys'
08-28 22:03:17.118 ? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
08-28 22:03:17.118 ? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
08-28 22:03:17.118 ? A/DEBUG: pid: 3089, tid: 8694, name: NPDecoder-CL  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
08-28 22:03:17.118 ? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xf3f48000
08-28 22:03:17.120 system_process W/NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 3089
08-28 22:03:17.122 ? A/DEBUG:     eax 002fd000  ebx f3f50eb4  ecx 000bd400  edx f4a4e81c
08-28 22:03:17.122 ? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
08-28 22:03:17.122 ? A/DEBUG:     esi e3e0b000  edi f3f48000
08-28 22:03:17.122 ? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000002b
08-28 22:03:17.122 ? A/DEBUG:     eip f3f4aa38  ebp 003fffc4  esp f31410f4  flags 00210206
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00002a38  /system/lib/libOpenglSystemCommon.so (goldfish_dma_write(goldfish_dma_context*, void*, unsigned int)+56)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00003853  /system/lib/libOpenglSystemCommon.so (ExtendedRCEncoderContext::lockAndWriteDma(void*, unsigned int)+67)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00003062  /system/lib/lib_renderControl_enc.so
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000314e  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.ranchu.so
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00009e67  /system/lib/libui.so (android::GraphicBufferMapper::unlock(native_handle const*)+71)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0012987d  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::SoftwareRenderer::render(void const*, unsigned int, long long, long long, void*, android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+813)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000dec7e  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onReleaseOutputBuffer(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+670)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000da678  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+6920)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000c9b9  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHandler::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+41)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00010ed2  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AMessage::deliver()+114)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000ddef  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+463)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000e7a3  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::LooperThread::threadLoop()+35)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00014aac  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+418)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 000141cf  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00081923  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 000227f2  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
08-28 22:03:17.124 ? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 000170b6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
08-28 22:03:17.201 ? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
08-28 22:03:17.202 system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
08-28 22:03:17.240 system_process W/AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died!
08-28 22:03:17.240 system_process W/AudioSystem: AudioPolicyService server died!
08-28 22:03:17.241  W/AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died!
08-28 22:03:17.241  W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
08-28 22:03:17.241  E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
08-28 22:03:17.241 ? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.audio_flinger' died
08-28 22:03:17.241 ? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.player' died
08-28 22:03:17.241 ? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.resource_manager' died
08-28 22:03:17.241 ? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.camera' died
08-28 22:03:17.241 ? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.audio_policy' died
08-28 22:03:17.241 ? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.radio' died
08-28 22:03:17.241 ? I/ServiceManager: service 'media.sound_trigger_hw' died
08-28 22:03:17.242  E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
08-28 22:03:17.243 system_process E/AudioService: Media server died.
08-28 22:03:17.248  D/VideoView: Error: 100,0
08-28 22:03:17.315  D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f81c1b54400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f81c1b5b460)
08-28 22:03:17.319 system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
08-28 22:03:17.463 ? I/mediaserver: ServiceManager: 0xf614c680
08-28 22:03:17.463 ? I/AudioFlinger: Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
08-28 22:03:17.465 ? I/CameraService: CameraService started (pid=8761)
08-28 22:03:17.465 ? I/CameraService: CameraService process starting
08-28 22:03:17.467 ? D/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient: Emulated camera list: 
08-28 22:03:17.467 ? D/EmulatedCamera_FakeCamera: Initialize: Fake camera is facing back
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with auto, 1.000000, 1.000000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with incandescent, 1.380000, 0.600000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with daylight, 1.090000, 0.920000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with twilight, 0.920000, 1.220000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: setWhiteBalanceMode with white balance auto
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? D/EmulatedCamera_FakeCamera: Initialize: Fake camera is facing front
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with auto, 1.000000, 1.000000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with incandescent, 1.380000, 0.600000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with daylight, 1.090000, 0.920000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: initializeWhiteBalanceModes with twilight, 0.920000, 1.220000
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? V/EmulatedCamera_Device: setWhiteBalanceMode with white balance auto
08-28 22:03:17.468 ? E/EmulatedCamera_Factory: 2 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
08-28 22:03:17.469 ? I/CameraService: Loaded "Emulated Camera Module" camera module
```

Comment: I think you re using the emulator - have you tried it on a real device? The emulator can have issues for video and cameras etc.

Comment: Thanks Mick and no I have not tried on real device yet,  but how come same code works on other emulators.

Comment: Emulators and video are always a little problematic - if you look through Stackoverflow you will see a fair few example issues. There will generally be some sensible root cause if you have time to find it, e.g. emulator;ator not supporting some profile or resolution on a particular platform, but at some point it becomes more time efficient to just find some way to test anything that fails on the emulator on a real device also.